# Dart: how to safely get an element from a nullable list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list that can possibly be null. How do I get an element from it using dart's null safety operators?

- `aNullList[0]`   (Will throw a null pointer)

Those don't compile:

- `aNullList?[0]`  (Don't compile)
- `aNullList?[0] ?? "None"`  (Also don't compile)

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `elementAt` in combination of null safe operators like this:

`aNullList?.elementAt(0) ?? "No elements"`